# Selenium open page and left click on a button to achieve click button result

Tags: python, html, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

URL = https://freemidi.org/download3-16514-a-powerful-friend--pet-shop-boys

Trying to use Python to open a web browser, insert and load the URL. And then ultimately save the midi file by clicking on the button or else right-clicking on the button save as. In fact, I am interested in all solutions to downloading this file using Python. When I inspect the button in Chrome I am provided with the following html:

```
<a rel="nofollow" id="downloadmidi" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" title="A  Powerful Friend " data-loading-text="loading..." href="getter-16514" download="">Download MIDI</a>
```

I decided to try make it right click and save the file

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import time

# Set up the Chrome driver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

# Navigate to the page
driver.get("https://freemidi.org/download3-16514-a-powerful-friend--pet-shop-boys")

# Find the download button
download_button = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'downloadmidi')

# Right click the download button
actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.context_click(download_button).perform()

# Wait for the right-click menu to appear
time.sleep(1)

# Press the 'Save link as...' option
actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.send_keys("v").perform()

# Wait for the save dialog to appear
time.sleep(1)

# Press the Enter key to save the file
actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.send_keys("\n").perform()

# Wait for the file to download
time.sleep(10)

# Close the driver
driver.quit()
```